# How to trigger ItemChange when a Task is updated?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I took this code from the internet to automatically send the tasks that are completed to a specific folder ("Completed Tasks"). It didn't work, I would click to complete the task and it wouldn't get moved.

I put msgboxes to pop up at three parts of the code to see where the problem is. The initialization box pops up, but the box corresponding to the ItemChange doesn't, and the other one doesn't as well. My impression is that the ItemChange isn't being called.

```vb
Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Items
    MsgBox ("initialized")
End Sub

Public Sub olItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim CompTaskf As Folder
    MsgBox ("detected change")
    
    If Item.Complete = True And Item.IsRecurring = False Then
        MsgBox ("condition met")
        Set CompTaskf = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Folders("Completed Tasks")
        Item.Move CompTaskf
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried:

- Changing the folder permissions and starting Outlook in administrator mode.
- Pointing it to a single folder with a few tasks.
- Setting CompTaskf as a global variable.

Edit: corrected myolItems to olItems, now it works but only if I point to a single folder with few tasks:
`Set myolItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Folders("Inbox").Items`

It doesn't work without the .Folders(Inbox")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought `.Items` wasn't returning the items when attached right after the default folder.
I found a way to point `olItems` to the current folder by defining it as so every time I switch folders.

```vb
Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items
Public WithEvents daFolder As Outlook.Explorer

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set daFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer
    'MsgBox ("initialized")
End Sub
'Sets daFolder as the active explorer window on startup, 
' apparently necessary because i can't put
' Application.ActiveExplorer_FolderSwitch() as the sub

Public Sub daFolder_FolderSwitch()
    Set olItems = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
End Sub
'Every time i switch between folders, set olItems as the items of the current folder

Public Sub olItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim CompTaskf As Folder
    'MsgBox ("detected change")
    If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" And Item.Complete = True And Item.IsRecurring = False Then 'This verification that it's a task item is necessary, otherwise the code may crash
        'MsgBox ("condition met")
        Set CompTaskf = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Folders("Completed Tasks") 'Set folder i want to move tasks to
        Item.Move CompTaskf 'Move task to the folder
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The olItems  variabel is never initialized. You are initializing the undeclared myolItems variable.

Comment: Ah, they are different because of a troubleshooting i tried but i really forgot to change what's being declared.
I made that change and tried pointing to a single folder with a few tasks again and it worked:
`Set myolItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Folders("Inbox").Items`
But i can't get it work without this .Folders("Inbox") part
Going to edit the thread